# How do I find out which UUID I should use to request data from my Polar H10 sensor?

Tags: uuid, sensors, bluetooth-gatt

I want to connect to my Polar H10 and read its Heart Rate (PPI) values. I am basically following [this](https://medium.com/swlh/creating-an-accelerometer-data-stream-with-polar-device-450a223f5789) example Python code which reads Acceleration from the same device. I am however stuck in finding out which UUID I should use to request the Heart Rate data. The example uses a byte array of unknown origin (to me) to request the Acceleration data and I have no clue where I should retrieve the UUID for heart rate from. All I can find is [this](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf) document, but it gives a, I believe hexidecimal, code which I cannot use. What do I do to get the right UUID? I'm new to this kind of sensor stuff so nothing seems obvious to me.

EDIT 1:

So these are the GATT characteristics on my device
[image: So these are the GATT characteristics on my device]

This is the PMD measurement type I am trying to extract
[image: This is the PMD measurement type I am trying to extract]

And of that I want Byte0: Heart rate in bpm
[image: And of that I want Byte0: Heart rate in bpm]

What I am doing now (I'm not sure if you want all the code so I'm gonna post what seems relevant). In Python:

For setting the request for specific data (I think? this is what the example does with different data from the same sensor)

```
ECG_WRITE = bytearray([0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x82, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x0E, 0x00])
```

What I've tried to change ECG data to heart rate data is:

```
RR_UUID = "0000180D-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
```

But I feel like it isn't working because it isn't a byte array.

Then later on these lines are executed for actual data retrievement I think (again, I'm following a guide I'm not 100% sure what the code does)

```
 
    att_read = await client.read_gatt_char(PMD_CONTROL)
    await client.write_gatt_char(PMD_CONTROL,  ECG_WRITE)

    ## ECG stream started
    await client.start_notify(PMD_DATA, data_conv)
```

And from there on the data_conv method converts the data into usable data, and in this same method I can just print out the data and see it. However, since I don't know what I should enter as byte array to request the heart rate data, I haven't been able to get any data out of it yet. It also gives no errors/exceptions whatshowever so I am not sure what is going wrong.
So I am working from a Windows computer using Python code, and the target machine is a Polar H10 heart sensor.

Comment: Those UUIDs show that it is a custom service so the documents on bluetooth.com are unlikely to be helpful. What value do you have for `PMD_DATA`? It looks like it should be `FB005C82-02E7-F387-1CAD-8ACD2D8DF0C8`.  Where is the documentation for `PMD_CONTROL`? What is the current value of `PMD_CONTROL` if you read it?

Comment: So the value I'm getting from PMD Control is \x0f\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 or  15 5 and a bunch of zero's.  And the document for the PMD documentation is this https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/blob/master/technical_documentation/Polar_Measurement_Data_Specification.pdf , the screenshots I posted are from there. What is the value I'm getting from pmd control supposed to mean?

Comment: The section in the documentation called `Read Features from device` seems to suggest that result shows the device only has: `ecg_supported` and `acc_supported`. It shows `ppi_supported` as `False` so not supported is my reading(`0x0F`= control point feature read response. `0x05` = `0b00000101` = PMD Mesurement Types). In the `Start Stream` section the examples shows getting `ACC` measurements which your devices supports so you could try that to prove you have the basic mechanisms correct

Comment: I'm confused. Do you read the ppi_supported = false from the "Read features from device" image in the docs, or from the response I got from PMD_CONTROL? Because I'm looking at the docs now and I'm pretty sure it says ppi_supported = true. And how does one generate the UUID for the request based on this?

Comment: The documentation says bit 3 of the second byte/octet in the returned value indicates if `ppi` is supported. bit 3 from your device was 0 which I'm assuming is false (e.g. not supported). Is that clearer?

Comment: Ok yes I now understand you. However, if true is 1 and false 0, the byte for the example response value for PMD measurement types should be 0b0111011, while the returned hexadecimal value of 0x6E is 0b1101110. Is it a coincidence that it's mirrored? I would also find it very odd that the ppi (containing heart beat/rate) would not be able to be extracted. And for the ecg for example. I know the byte array for the request through the guide, but how would I construct it myself? What is it based on?

Comment: Convention in positional notation is writing less significant digits (bit0) further to the right. So `ecg_supported` is bit 0 or the furthest right digit. As you say `0x6E` is `0b01101110` so `ecg_supported` (the right most digit) is 0 (or False) which agrees with what they wrote "bit0 ecg_support=false".  They have written "bit3 ppi_supported=true" which is only correct if bit 0 is on the right.

Comment: @ManoloVisoRomero The article that you have following is not available at the moment. I'm also currently working on a similar project and struggling with connecting the h10 sensor to the Windows 11 laptop. can you please suggest some sources

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve the same problem for some time now and finally got the hang of it.

The documentation is confusing as it leads one to think that the H10 sensor doesn't support HR and PPI readings. The reality, however, is that those measurements are *of course* supported by the sensor—just not through the `PMD_DATA` stream. The UUID for HR readings is:

```
HR_UUID = "00002A37-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
```

So when you start a `client.notify(HR_UUID)`, you will get a 6 byte data stream, that follows the specifications given in the Polar Specification Document (see image below)

[image: PPI frame types]

Comment: Where did you get that image from? Can you be sure to include a citation for it?

Comment: @JeremyCaney It is from the official polar documentation